# Vlookup in excel macro

Tags: vba, excel, vlookup

I am trying to retrieve the value based on a key in another excel sheet but it does not seem to be retrieving it so I am wondering if my code is correct:

```
Sheets("Details").Cells(rrow, 9).Value = Application.WorkSheetsFunc.VLookup(Cells(rrow, 4).Value, Sheets("Address").Range("G5693:G5843"), 3, False)
```

Anybody know if the syntax is correct or is anything wrong with my code ?

Comment: `WorkSheetsFunc` ?? should be `WorksheetFunction` , just a Typo, Don't forget to qualify `Cells(rrow, 4).Value` with it's `Worksheet`

Comment: Your lookup range is a single column but you are looking for a result in the 3rd column of the lookup range.

Comment: @MarkFitzgerald I changed it to Range("A5693:L5843") but it prompts me an error saying subscript out of range

Comment: Is `rrow` defined as a long?  What is its value when called?

Comment: I am running a For loop to loop through all the rows in my current sheet. I declared it as For rrow = 7 to 200

Comment: 1. Make sure that the sheet `Address` exists or you get error 9 out of range (check for typos). 2. If your lookup range is `Range("A5693:L5843")` then the value of `Cells(rrow, 4).Value` has to exist in row `A5693` to `A5843` if not it will throw an error 1004.

Comment: `Tools ► Options ► set Require Variable Declaration`.  Put `Option Explicit` at top of your macro and declare all variables.  Step through your code to see if the values show what they should.  Post back with the rest of your code if still an issue.

Answer (score 2):

Few suggestions:

Qualify the lookup value Cells(rrow, 4).Value with the sheet reference. Which sheet this cell belongs to? Otherwise it will refer to the activesheet only.
Also make sure rrow is not null in the code.

When retrieving the value through VLookUp, first check if the lookup value is found in lookup column and if yes, proceed for Vlookup to get the desired value from the desired column.
Considering lookup_table is Range("A5693:L5843"), the lookup value must be present in the first column i.e. in this case Range("A5693:A5843").

```
If Application.CountIf(Sheets("Address").Range("A5693:A5843"), Cells(rrow, 4).Value) > 0 Then
    Sheets("Details").Cells(rrow, 9).Value = Application.WorkSheetsFunc.VLookup(Cells(rrow, 4).Value, Sheets("Address").Range("G5693:G5843"), 3, False)
End If
```